# Z-stacking two sibling divs

Tags: css, html, layout

I have essentially the following div arrangement:

```
<div id="parent" style="height:100%">
    <div id="sibling1" style="height:100%;position:relative"></div>
    <div id="sibling2" style="position:relative"></div>
</div>
```

What I want is a clean and elegant way to make sibling2 ignore the presence of sibling1, such that it will appear on top of it.  Positioning them absolutely would disrupt the order of the document, so that will not work here.  Essentially, the **only change I'm trying to make is for one sibling to ignore another sibling without any other side-effects,** and highly preferably without making the code messy or disjoint.

I've read about recommendations from people to do somewhat of a hack by making one of them an absolute child of a relative zero-width zero-height div, so that the lower sibling div will think that its upper sibling isn't taking up any space, but that messes up the first one, since it's contained within different a div now, thus losing width and height (among other) information of the original parent.

Comment: Didn't understood what are you asking here, do you want a div top of another div?

Comment: When I say z-stacking, I am referring to literally stacking two sibling divs along the Z-axis (one showing up in front of another).  In essence, I want sibling2 to ignore the presence of sibling1, but without messing anything else up.

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/A684W/)?

Comment: That looks very intriguing, and at first glance appears to satisfy my requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately, upon further investigation, this seems to be causing abnormal behavior.  If I proceed to place a paragraph tag inside of the sibling div, its effects are for whatever reason inflicted upon its parent!  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/5y2Lt/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5y2Lt/3/ ?

Comment: No Sergio.  Look at all the space above the red one.  That space is caused by that <p> tag, which is INSIDE it.  So, in other words, the P tag inside the div is pushing the div tag down, somehow and for whatever reason.

Comment: @LeviDettwyler It seems like you are changing some things here http://jsfiddle.net/5y2Lt/4/

Comment: Yes, but nothing significant.  What you posted there exhibits the same problem.  With the <p> tags, everything gets shifted down for some reason.

Comment: What do you mean shifted down? You mean the natural margin/padding of the p tag?

Comment: Take the <p> tag out of the first sibling.  Then put it back in.  Compare.  Note how the sibling which contains the <p> tag gets shifted down.  Something tells me that this isn't normal behavior.